# how to split a list into groups by week in scala

Tags: list, scala, split

```
case class Test(dayOfWeek:Int,b:Int=Random.nextInt)
val data=(3 to 100).map(_ % 7).map(Test(_))
```

how to split the data into groups, each group have one week's data, if a week is not complete, also have a group. So the group should be

```
Group 1: (3,4,5,6)   // the number here is the dayOfWeek
Group 2: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 3: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
...
last Group:(0,1,2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala's collections are really powerful, this should do it in a couple of lines:

```
val (firstWeek, nextWeeks) = data.span(_.dayOfWeek != 0)
val weeks = (firstWeek :: nextWeeks.grouped(7).toList).dropWhile(_.isEmpty)
```

Look at the doc for `span` and `grouped` [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.IndexedSeq).

```
println(weeks.zipWithIndex.map {
  case (week, i) => s"Group $i: (${week.map(_.dayOfWeek).mkString(",")})"
}.mkString("\n"))
```

outputs:

```
Group 0: (3,4,5,6)
Group 1: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 2: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
[snip]
Group 12: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 13: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 14: (0,1,2)
```

Comment: Yes, that's the elegance I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a fold:

```
case class Test(dayOfWeek: Int, b: Int = scala.util.Random.nextInt)
val data = (3 to 100).map(_ % 7).map(Test(_))

val spans =
  data.foldLeft(Vector(Vector.empty[Test])) {
    case (zs :+ z, e) =>
      if (e.dayOfWeek == 0)
        if (z.nonEmpty)
          (zs :+ z) :+ Vector(e)
        else
          zs :+ Vector(e)
      else
        zs :+ (z :+ e)
  }

for ((g, i) <- spans.zipWithIndex) {
  println(f"Group $i: (${g.map(_.dayOfWeek).mkString(",")})")
}
```

Output:

```
Group 0: (3,4,5,6)
Group 1: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 2: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 3: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 4: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 5: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 6: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 7: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 8: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 9: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 10: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 11: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 12: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 13: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 14: (0,1,2)
```

Comment: I think if the first element is a 0, you'll end up with a empty group at the beginning. For example, `val data = (0 to 10).map(_ % 7).map(Test(_))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive version that works on general sequences and now requires a `weekDay` function.

```
def groupByWeek[T](s: Seq[T], maxDay: Int = 6, weekDay: T => Int) = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def recurse(r: Seq[T], results: Seq[Seq[T]]): Seq[Seq[T]] =
    r.splitAt(r.indexWhere(item => weekDay(item) == maxDay)) match {
      case (hd, tl) if (hd.isEmpty && tl.isEmpty) => results
      case (hd, tl) if (hd.isEmpty) => results :+ tl
      case (hd, tl) => recurse(tl.tail, results :+ (hd :+ tl.head))
    }
  recurse(s,Seq.empty)
  }
}
```

Called like this:

```
val weeks = groupByWeek(data, weekDay = (x:Test) => x.dayOfWeek)
```

And you can see the groups:

```
println(weeks.zipWithIndex.map {
  case (week, i) => s"Group $i: (${week.map(_.dayOfWeek).mkString(",")})"
}.mkString("\n"))
```

Which outputs:

```
Group 0: (3,4,5,6)
Group 1: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 2: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
[snip]
Group 12: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 13: (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
Group 14: (0,1,2)
```